# How to generate a pulse signal for the GPIO pins in python?

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, gpio

I am working on the beaglebone black and was trying to generate a pulse signal.. The beaglebone black is connected to the Mcp23017 via the i2c.. I wanted to generate the pulse signal for a specific pin of the MCP23017..

I found an easy to use library for the [beaglebone](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python). Using this I have can set my pins to High/Low Inputs/Outputs.. However now in I want to create a small trigger like functionality where in I could trigger a particular GPIO pin of the MCP and then read the corresponding pin data.. 
The part that I am stuck with is on how to create this particular trigger function.. Could someone please give me a small description on how to go about this..

This is the code that I have tried:

For setting the pin6 as output :

```
 subprocess.call('i2cset , -y, 0, 0x20, 0x00, 0xFF', shell=True)
```

For setting this pin6 high or low:

```
 subprocess.call('i2cset, -y, 0, 0x20, 0x15, 0x40', shell=True)
```

Now I need to create a trigger pulse so that it can be given to each pin individually and the pin status could be read to see how it reacts to the trigger..

I thought I could use the edge triggered functionality of the Adafruit library but I dont kn ow as to how to implement this for the pins (ex:pin6) of the MCP via the I2C bus

Comment: How does `tkinter` fit into this?

Comment: I have created a gui using tkinter to set the MCP23017 pins.. Now within the gui I wanted to create a button that could generate this pulse..

Comment: Well, then you obviously should create a function that sends the pulse and create a button that calls the function when clicked. Where do you get stuck *exactly*?

Comment: @fhdrsdg: Sry for the late response.. Was on a holiday.. I am stuck in the part where the pulse needs to be generated.. I have created the function with a radio button in Tkinter, but stuck at the pulse generation..  I was wondering for the pulse would it be okay if I just toggle the pins to high and low for a certain period of time..?

Comment: Alright, then tkinter isn't part of the problem and shouldn't be part of the question, it's confusing. You should focus on generating the pulse signal on the beaglebone. I would recommend you to *thoroughly* read [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to be more clear about exactly what problem you are facing. Also include what you have tried and didn't work and why you feel just toggling a pin might not be okay.

Comment: @fhdrsdg: Thank you for that link.. I redid my question.. Hopefully now its easier to understand..

Comment: Can you post the code demonstrating what you've already tried?

Comment: Hi @NamitaRaju this is still confusing to me. You say you need a way to generate a pulse signal, then you show how you have already achieved this (using i2cset), then you say you need some sort of "trigger pulse" (is this not the pulse signal?) and that you want to read some data via the MCP... I don't think the question here is necessarily vague but it sort of jumps about a lot. Can you reword it perhaps?